# How to hold called function until document.body not return complete

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am creating a function `alerts()` and call it in my script tag, that is in `<head>`
Actully currenty i am woking on live editor,so i have to put users code in head,normally all function call in head but here ,it shows error ! 
I want to hold the user code and run when DOM completes! 
like:

**HTML**

```
   <head>
     <script src='alertResource.js' type ='text/javascript' ></script>

      <script>

          alerts();

      <script>

  </head>
```

**alertResource.js**

```
 function alerts(msg) {
    var _M_DoWn = { x: '', y: '', isdown: '' };
    var _A = document.createElement('HTML_alert');
     _A.id = "codeit_HTML_alert";

     insertAfter(document.body, _A);

 }

  function insertAfter(refrNode, newNode) {
   refrNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, refrNode.nextSibling);
  }
```

So, whenever I call the `alerts()` it shows me an error in my console :

**Error**

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null*

I guess the error appears because my function gets called before DOM is loaded. Now I want to do something like: delay any function call until DOM is ready. I know how to check readystate but not able to implement it, as per my case.

Any idea? What I need to do to achieve this?

Comment: You can also use
    $(document).ready(function(){
       //code
    });

Comment: what i also use? @Akh

Comment: sorry by mistake i wrote that

Comment: @Akh ,Thanks for reply but,,I am not using `Jquery` in my `DOC`.

Comment: @AshishMishra so why using tag jQuery in your question?

Comment: Then add javascript code or refrence at bottom of html ie in last of html code

Comment: @Akh It is good to add code at bottom ?

Comment: @AshishMishra yes it is best practice.

Answer (score 1):

call your function after page is completely loaded by using this:

Using `JavaScriopt`

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
     alerts();
}, false);
```

---

Using `JQuery`

```
$(function(){
     alerts();
});
```

Comment: Any similar solution in javascript ??

Comment: @AshishMishra see how jQuery implement it, e.g: http://stackoverflow.com/a/800010/1414562

Comment: best way is to add javascript code or refrence at bottom of html ie in last of html code

Comment: @Akh i guess you mean just before closing `</body>` tag, that's the simplest way for sure

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes before closing body tag

Comment: but is it good way? if user write its "own function" inside this function,and call from onclick in HTML then the function inside load is run or not?

Comment: generally good coding practice is to use every user interaction after page is completely loaded, because it may be possible that many functions are loaded from outside the page. we can proceed after that external files are loaded into out page, so don't worry about this scenario if you don't have heavy content that affect parsing of web page.

Comment: Thanks @Nikhil Butani, I will try for this...:)

Answer (score 1):

When you call to "alerts" the document is not fully loaded and "refrNode.parentNode" return null.

Try this, without jQuery

```
<body onLoad="alerts();">
....
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this. (Javascript way)

```
window.onload=function(){SomeJavaScriptCode};
<body onload="SomeJavaScriptCode">
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on if you need to support IE8 or not, you could do this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  alerts();
});
```